# Healing in the Torah and Talmud, how to receive healing from Hashem?

Tags: medicine, sin, repentance-teshuvah

Healing in the Torah and Talmud, how to receive it? We see many in the Torah are healed by Hashem. I wonder is there some knowledge how to receive it and what is the connection? Like if you have pain in the left arm and it feels weak, is it connected with some kind of sin, is body-parts a metaphor for something we need to understand?

Comment: Are you asking about Mida-Kneked-Mida?

Comment: Are you asking in a figurative sense? In a metaphysical sense? Are you looking for a Kabbalistic answer? Are you looking for a map of the body correlating to certain commandments?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

There is a book called Sefer Haredim that classifies Mitsvoss following the human organs.

See in Sefer Hahinuch Mizvah 169

ולכן הזהירתנו התורה כי בהגיע אל האדם החלי הרע, והוא הצרעת, שלא יקחנו דרך מקרה, רק יחשב מיד כי עונותיו גרמו וירחיק מחברת בני אדם כאדם המרחק מרע מעשיו, ויתחבר אל המכפר המרפא שבר החטא ויראה אליו נגעו, ובעצתו ובדבריו ובפשפוש מעשיו יוסר מעליו הנגע, כי האל ברוך הוא שמשגיח עליו תמיד יראה מעשה תשובתו וירפאהו, וזהו ענין ההסגרין כמו שאמרנו.‏

The principle is that the ill man should know that there is nothing random.
But the mean to know what is the problem is little, and a phantasmal interpretation does not help. And it is very cruel to make people feel guilty when ill. The pseudo-cabalistic approach is not a genuine Jewish approach.

Comment: Read my comments under Aleksandr`s answer..

Answer (score -1):

The Torah heals by telling us that prayer heals.

The Jewish book of healing was destroyed so that people will pray.

Mishna Brochos 5.5

> They used to say about him, about Rabbi Chanina ben Dosa: When he would pray for the sick, he would say: This one will live and this one will die. They said to him: How do you know? He replied to them: If the prayer is fluent in my mouth, I know that it has been accepted; and if not, then I know that it has been torn up.

Quotes on subject:

> תורה מגנא ומצלא, ‏

From [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA)

> לעולם יבקש אדם רחמים שלא יחלה, שאם יחלה אומרים ו הבא זכות והפטר
>
> יפה תפילת החולה עצמו מתפילת אחרים עליו, והיא קודמת להתקבל
>
> רְפָאֵנוּ ה' וְנֵרָפֵא. הושִׁיעֵנוּ וְנִוָּשֵׁעָה כִּי תְהִלָּתֵנוּ אָתָּה. וְהַעֲלֵה רְפוּאָה שְׁלֵמָה לְכָל מַכּותֵינוּ כִּי אֵל מֶלֶךְ רופֵא נֶאֱמָן וְרַחֲמָן אָתָּה. בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה', רופֵא חולֵי עַמּו יִשרָאֵל:‏
>
> תפילת הציבור, נשמעת תמיד; ואפילו היו בהן חטאים, אין הקדוש ברוך הוא מואס תפילתן של רבים.  לפיכך צריך אדם לשתף עצמו עם הציבור, ולא יתפלל יחידי, כל זמן שיכול להתפלל בציבור.  ולעולם ישכים אדם ויעריב לבית הכנסת, שאין תפילתו של אדם נשמעת בכל עת, אלא בבית הכנסת.  וכל מי שיש לו בית הכנסת בעירו, ואינו נכנס לתוכה להתפלל--נקרא שכן רע

Answer (score -1):

I know from Zohar I think that fingers of hands (and feet) represent 10 commandments. Right arm first five and left arm second five. So if you have a pain in the right arm it is likely you are violating all first five commandments. If it is just one finger then it is just one commandment.

Tabernacle (and Temple) were also designed to mimic human body of sorts. I.e Ark was the head/brain. Altar for Slaughters was a stomach etc. Please see Vaikra 15:31 and Bemidbar 19:13

Not to mention that all measurements in the Torah have something to do with human body. I.e cubit is a forearm, omer - handfuls, e.t.c.

Otherwise Torah says that God is your healer and if you live by the Torah you will never be ill.(Shemot 15:26)

I also think that Devarim 2:20 for example refers to healers (רפאים rpaim) Not sure about this one though...

Comment: Good answer,I dont understand the downvote,interesting answer.

Comment: "Tabernacle (and Temple) were also designed to mimic human body of sorts. I.e Ark was the head/brain. Altar for Slaughters was a stomach etc."   Is this from the Zohar?Or some other literature.I know the body is the temple of Hahsem ,but where can I read about the connection?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the source. I do not study Jewish tradition as much as I used to :) Look online.

Comment: @Eagel Please see Vaikra 15:31 and Bemidbar 19:13. These are one of the few verses from the actual Torah that I know of.

Comment: 1. Rabbi Chaim of Volozhin, the renowned student of the Gaon of Vilna, said that the commandment to
construct a Tabernacle is primarily a personal commandment; every Jew is "a living tabernacle in
miniature." HaShem rests the Shechinah, His Divine Presence, primarily in the human heart.
2. Sefer Charedim – The Book of the Awestruck (R. Eliezer Azkari, c. 1550) 66:27 – “You are a Temple
for the presence of the Holy King!”

Comment: The Beit HaMikdash is a macrocosm of the human body: if you look at a plan of the Sanctuary, you
will notice that the placement of the various vessels, the altar, the table, and the Menorah all
corresponds to the location of the vital organs in the human body. In other words, each of the
Temple's vessels represents a human organ. The 613 mitzvot (statutes of the “hedge”) directly
correlate to the 613 parts of the human body. 248 positive Mitzvot and 365 injunctions.
613 Human body parts - 248 limbs and 365 sinews.
613 Different parts and vessels in the Mishkan (Tabernakle).

Comment: Head & Brain = the Holy of Holies & Ark contained the two tablets. Just as a brain has two hemispheres, the right and
the left, so too there were two tablets. Just as the brain is triply encased in a skull with two membranes, the tablets
were also encased in three boxes.
Cranial Membrane = Curtain.
Eyes = Menorah + Showbread.
Ears = Chamber of Hewn Stone where the Sanhedrin met to hear cases
Nose = Golden Altar of Incense
Mouth = Door to the Holy place
Salivary glands = Laver.
Heart = The base of the altar, where blood was poured.

Comment: Stomach = Altar upon which the sacrifices were offered and consumed.

Comment: The sacrifices were also called food.
Umbilical cord = The smoke from the altar
Esophagus = Altar Ramp.
Sex organs = Fifteen steps between the men‟s and women‟s courtyards, and the rooms for storage of instruments, etc.
The Levitical choir would sing the fifteen Psalms / Songs of Ascent while standing on these fifteen steps, during
Succoth (Tabernacles), the quintessential picture of the marital chamber.
Skin = Wall
Ashes = Waste
Fetus = Giant lampstands In the Courtyard